# Using < or <= make different results when sort

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, sorting, built-in-symbols

```
Sort[{{a, 2}, {d, 4}, {c, 4}}, #1[[2]] < #2[[2]] &]
(* Out: {{a, 2}, {c, 4}, {d, 4}} *)
    
Sort[{{a, 2}, {d, 4}, {c, 4}}, #1[[2]] <= #2[[2]] &]
(* Out: {{a, 2}, {d, 4}, {c, 4}} *)
```

Could you explain why the two outputs are different ?

Mathematica's first answer is not my favorite. I think Mathematica should leave the order of `{d, 4}, {c, 4}` untouched since the order of `{d, 4}, {c, 4}`  **did not violate the criteria** `#1[[2]] < #2[[2]]`.

Comment: Notice what the second argument of `Sort` is: it is a two-argument function that should return `True` when two elements are in order and `False` if they are not. The appropriate function is thus `<=` or `>=` and _not_ `<` or `>`.

Comment: BTW you probably want `SortBy` here.

Comment: You want a "stable" sort. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304632/stable-sorting-ie-minimally-disruptive-sorting for example.

Comment: Please, how is that different from the difference between "<" and " <= "?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The pair `{{d, 4}, {c, 4}}` does violate the order `#1[[2]] < #2[[2]]`:

```
4 < 4
(* False *)
```

and this truth value makes `Sort` to determine that `{d, 4}` has higher order than `{c, 4}` and doesn't compare the two again. If you want the sort function to be strict, try

```
Sort[{{a, 2}, {d, 4}, {c, 4}},
  Which[ #1[[2]] < #2[[2]], True,
         #1[[2]] > #2[[2]], False ] &
]
(*{{a, 2}, {d, 4}, {c, 4}}*)
```

which gives null truth value ('untouched') to the pairs not satisfying the criteria.